# How to link static library created using ndk-build in android

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

How to link static library created using ndk-build in android

system.loadLibrary failed to found  my static library which is in libs/armeadi/libexample.a
i am using ndk r4.What i shouild put in android make file related to static library to get it linked with my android application.Where i should upgrade to ndk r5?

Answer (score 1):

What does your loadLibrary call look like? Based on the information you've provided, it should be `System.loadLibrary("example");`.

NDK 4 should not cause any problems.

Comment: but still unable to link my static library. i tried System.loadLibrary("example")l.but still no success

Answer (score 1):

Try to build a .so (dynamic library) with the static library.
see the two-libs example provided by android-ndk.
This http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/c2c4fbbdaabfeaa9/62e5ec07686e5157?lnk=gst&q=loading++static+library#62e5ec07686e5157 shall help.